# Can't keep div/textarea on top of mobile keyboard in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have the following code for the div:

**HTML**

```
<div id="input">
     <table id="submit">
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <form id="one">
                     <textarea id="one_inside"></textarea>
                 </form>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <input "submit_two" type="button"/>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#input{
    border: solid black 1px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:12%;
}
#submit{
    width: 100%;
}
#one_inside{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

But the keyboard always gets on the way of the textarea when it is focused and blockes the view. How can I always keep the div at the bottom of the mobile browser but on top of the keyboard not to block the view?

Comment: @HunterTurner can't you really help me?